# Links between containers not working with docker-compose version 2

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Linking between containers in a *version 2* docker-compose file is not working.

Only when using the 'old' *version 1* format, I do see the link in /etc/hosts of the container.

I have the following basic version 2 *docker-compose.yml* file.

```
version: '2'

services:
  my-app:
    image: tomcat:8.0
    container_name: my-app1
    links:
      - my-redis
  my-redis:
    image: redis
    container_name: my-redis1
```

When I run the following command:

```
docker-compose up -d
```

I see that two containers are started, but **no link is created** in the /etc/hosts file:

```
docker exec -it my-app1 cat /etc/hosts
```

```
    127.0.0.1       localhost
    ::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
    fe00::0 ip6-localnet
    ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
    ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
    ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
    172.18.0.3      2abb84ccada9
```

From 'my-app1' I can ping the other container using the IP address of 'my-redis1', but I cannot 'ping my-redis1' (based on a name).

What could be the problem here?

Additional information:

- Docker version 1.10.0, build 590d5108
- docker-compose version 1.6.0, build d99cad6
- Linux kernel: 4.3.5-300.fc23.x86_64

Comment: Docker 1.10 no longer uses `/etc/hosts` it uses an embedded DNS server. There is a known issue with the dns server and firewald running on the host. That might be causing the problem. You should be able to ping using both the container name and the service name.

Comment: Thanks, the problem was the firewall on the host (Fedora).
Docker containers are supposed to provide isolation from the host, but the new networking seem to be quite picky on the host configuration :-( ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is the firewalld of my Fedora host.

With the firewall temporarily disabled ('systemctl stop firewalld', followed by 'systemctl restart docker') everything works according to the docker documentation.

There seems to be a major problem with firewalld when used with docker, see: https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/16137.

Note that RHEL/Centos 7 also use firewalld.

-Arjen

Answer (score 14):

With version 2 of docker-compose the 'services' (containers) that are in the same network are linked between them by default.

Using the below docker-compose.yml file

```
version: '2'

services:
  my-app:
    image: tomcat:8.0
    container_name: my-app1
    links:
      - my-redis
  my-redis:
    image: redis
    container_name: my-redis1
```

You just can execute `ping my-app` from your `my-redis` container and `ping my-redis` from your `my-app` container to check that they are linked.

For instance:

```
$ docker-compose up -d
$ docker exec -it my-app1 bash
# ping my-redis
```

You can get more information about that in the links below:
https://blog.docker.com/2016/02/compose-1-6/
https://github.com/docker/compose/blob/master/docs/networking.md

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

However I cannot ping 'my-redis1' from 'my-app1' and the other way around.
I can only ping using the IP address.
The name 'my-redis1' does not appear in /etc/hosts of 'my-app1'. 
When I check 'docker network ls' I see that docker-compose has created a new network.

When I use a version 1 docker-compose file I do see 'my-redis1' in the /etc/hosts file of 'my-app1'.

Comment: PS. Also when I remove the link from the version2 docker-compose file, I cannot ping 'my-redis1' from 'my-app1' using 'ping my-redis1'.

Comment: I think that you have to make a ping to the service name (`ping my-app`), not to the container name. Could you double-check if the command that I commented above works?

Comment: I can only ping between containers using the IP address, not through 'ping my-app' or 'ping my-app1'.
Should 'my-app' appear in the /etc/hosts file of 'my-redis'?

Comment: I have tried to reproduce the issue but I have not been able to. I updated the answer with the steps that I followed, could you double checked? The 'my-app' should not have to appear there.

Comment: Hi, I just discovered that the problem is the firewall on my Linux Fedora host.
When I disable the firewall (systemctl stop firewalld) I am able to ping from one container to the other.

Comment: Interesting... I'm glad to know that you solve the issue and thanks for letting us know :)

Comment: Thanks very much for your support!

Comment: Fantastic answer! This is going to save me a lot of time

Comment: `ping my-redis` or `ping my-redis1` ?

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was in service name.

```
version: "2"
services:
    my_auth_server:
       build: auth-server
       ports: 
           - "8082:8082"

    my_api:
       build: core-api
       ports: 
           - "8081:8081"   
       links:
           - my_auth_server:auth-server # <-- here changed from auth_server to auth-server
```